# Cross-compilation targeting Cygwin with Linux host

Tags: linux, cygwin, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, msys2

Is it possible to cross-compile a program targeting a Cygwin environment from a Linux/Unix host? I'm mostly trying to avoid using a Windows (virtual) machine for building a collection of programs.

From [the website](https://www.cygwin.com/):

> Cygwin is not:
>
> - a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your application *from source* if you want it to run on Windows.

[mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) is not enough, I need a full POSIX platform. I'm also wondering if it's possible to target [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Perhaps I do not understand correctly, and one doesn't need to compile *in* Cygwin, but only mingw-w64 is necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to compile for Cygwin from Linux.
The cygwin1.dll itself is built in such way.

Packages/libraries are available at:

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/yselkowitz/cygwin/

Of course only a minimal set of tools/libraries is available

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. To use the rpm's under Ubuntu (and probably Debian as well) you can use alien to convert them. It has to be (for the Fedora 36 rpm's) an Ubuntu 22.04 else libc is too old. This also works inside a (docker) container. You have to install cygwin-binutils-generic,
cygwin-gcc-common
cygwin64
cygwin64-binutils-2.39
cygwin64-cpp-11.2.0
cygwin64-gcc-11.2.0
cygwin64-w32api-runtime and
libisl15-0.18 (from for example opensuse)